# Windows 8.1 - Betta fish is missing from start menu screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Recently, I've upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. Now I have Windows 8.1 x 64 SL Edition. Everything is working like charm. But I noticed that the betta fish start screen background is missing. I have seen many start screens featuring betta fish like the screenshot below;

[image: Screenshot]

Below is a screenshot of available start screens in my windows 8.1.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get betta fish into my start screen? I don't want to add betta fish like downloading the blue fish background to my PC, and use it since it will give me no customization, and I will get just the blue fish. I want it to be customizable like other backgrounds (like changing the color)

Comment: I am pretty sure that background only existed in the Develoepr Preview version of Windows 8.0

Answer (score 0):

The background only existed for the Preview version of Windows 8.0.